# JQuery not updating hidden field

Tags: php, jquery

The following code should update a hidden field on form submit but it simply does not and I'm struggling as to know why?

Code snippet:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.slideviewer.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**UPDATE** changed the code as suggested, see below, but, still no joy - also tried img:first as suggested but no different

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#wl_add" ).submit( function ( event ) { /* form name wl_add */
          $( this ).find( "input[name='item_pic_url']" )
                   .val( $( "#mygalthree img" ).attr( 'src' ) );
          } );
  });
</script>

<div id="mygalthree" class="svw"><ul>
<?PHP

foreach($html->find('img') as $e){ // from simple_html_dom

    $image = $e->src;

    echo '<li><img src="'.$image.'" width=300 alt="" /></li>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_pic_url" value="'.$image.'" />';

?>

</ul></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your submit handler? Do you know for sure its being invoked?

Comment: Can you show the HTML that is sent down to the browser without the PHP code inserted?

Comment: Because there are many images in mygalthree div..Use this..$( "#mygalthree img:first" ).attr( 'src' )

Comment: @jrummell how would I do that? can you give example pls, quite new to this

Comment: @DarrenSweeney all modern browsers come with javascript debugging tools. For example, in Chrome, you can open developer tools by pressing F12 and then use the Scripts tab to set a break point in your javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should setup event handlers inside [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $( "#wl_add" ).submit( function ( event ) { /* form name wl_add */
     $( this ).find( "input[name='item_pic_url']" )
     .val( $( "#mygalthree img" ).attr( 'src' ) );

     } );
});
</script>
```

Otherwise, script will try to bind submit to form that does not yet exist, so you do not get submit handler bound and executed.

Comment: This is one of the first things on the `How jQuery Works` page: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: @archil Thanks.. OK, changed it to this but still does not overwrite the current value which is last image in the UL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the php loop runs more than once, you will have a problem identifying your images and your inputs as there are multiple elements `$( "#mygalthree img" )` and multiple `input[name='item_pic_url']` as all inputs have the same name.

**Edit:** To clarify, if you look at the manual for [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), you will see:

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.

So in your code:

```
 $( this ).find( "input[name='item_pic_url']" )
   .val( $( "#mygalthree img" ).attr( 'src' ) );
```

you are setting the value of **all** your hidden input elements to the source of the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
$(this).find.....
```

to:

```
$('input[name="item_pic_url"]').val($('#mygalthree img').attr('src'));
```

Here's a simple example through jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/9DTUD/1/